Показать пользовательские поля для товара WooCommerce
Подскажите, как у товара WooCommerce, на примере обжаренного кофе, можно показать его качество (насыщенность, кислинка, горчинка, сладость)?

Я даже не знаю, с чего начать. В плагине пользовательских полей ACF и других плагинах доп. полей товара, я такого нигде не видел. Как это можно сделать?

"такого" - это какого? Это и есть доп поля.


Я даже не знаю, с чего начать.

Доп поля.
Готовые плагины для этого

Я их все пересмотрел. Там нет того, что нужно. Вот какое поле вы поставили бы, к примеру?

Что значит "какое"? Какое нужно в конкретной ситуации. И в плагинах всё есть. Они для этого и предназначены.

Если бы там все было, я не просил бы помощи ((

На данный момент, в этих плагинах не получится вывести информацию о качестве кофе, как на изображениях в моем вопросе. Может только в ACF, но зачем ради небольшого кода ставить целый плагин? Скорее всего, можно написать кастомный код. К примеру, при создании вариативного товара, админ также заполняет несколько полей со значениями от 1 до 5. Каждое значение стилизуется в виде блока с заполнением цветом. И в зависимости от значений, показывается от 1 до 5 блоков. Вот только как это реализовать без плагина?

Всё с плагинами получится... при условии наличия знаний css (если нужно в точности как на картинках) и прямых рук .
